# PayPal integrating Donation button on Premier account

Tags: paypal, integration

I have PayPal Premier account already integrating cart upload with encrypted parameters and it all works fine on one site.

Now on another I want to add Donate button. Nothing fancy, no encryption, user enters his own amount into the box. However there are problems:

- Premier account as I understand is supposed along with Business type to support Donation buttons - account is of type Premier but there is no option to create donation button (there are all others - Add to cart, Buy Now, Subscribe...) when I am logged in and go to button creation wizard.
- My country can accept and withdraw money from PayPal (it already works for upload cart which is way more complex than this) as I researched it needs to be able to withdraw funds. It is.
- Account also needs to be verified. It is.
- There could be some payment blocking turned on. Although I might have missed something here I went through all options and nothing seems to be blocked.

So the Donate button is missing from the wizard when I am logged in. But I am clever and I can beat the system - so I logged out and created Donate button (it is available when logged out in the wizard). No cigar. After clicking on such integrated button from the site and wanting to donate the error message pops out:

**Your recipient is not able to receive funds at this time. Your recipient must first set up his or her account to receive funds.**

What needs to be set up?

The full implementation of this is like 10 minutes of work total but I am obviously missing one tiny little detail to make it work.

I already looked for all kinds of forum topics/posts and contacted PayPal but got no reply from them at all so asking around is my last resort. A guy says he solved it by creating button after being logged out. Didn't help me due to error message above. Another says he had Business account and had no Donation button in the wizard. PayPal forum has similar topic but the answers there are pointing to blocked payments which I verified above.

So I am low on remaining options - what is going on here and where is the fish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you're certain the email address on your account is confirmed?
If so, you're unfortunately out of luck; donation buttons are not allowed in all countries.

Comment: PayPal site says: "Accept donations in 24 currencies from 190 countries and markets worldwide.". I would say that this 190 countries is pretty much the same ones that accept "BuyNow" as well which already works (along with Subscribe and AddToCart) so why would Donate have special treatment? Email address is confirmed, yes.

Comment: I found that there is a case that Donate may not be available under Premier account because under some local laws in some countries it is considered personal payment so it needs personal account. But I have a personal account too and no donate button there either (but there are others - BuyNow, AddToCart and Subscribe same as Premier account).

Comment: It's got nothing to do with a Personal / Premier account. And yes, donations are restricted in particular countries. Which country are you in? (Or more specifically, in which country is your PayPal account registered?)

Comment: Account is registered for Croatia. Does that help?

Comment: I've given up this, most probably this donate is not available and nobody everywhere I looked seems interested into finding a solution including PayPal forum, PayPal user support. So I've found different solution and marked this as an answer although it didn't really help.

Comment: Donations are indeed not allowed in Croatia.

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick in my mind. Choose a "buy button" and use [this image](https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif) as your button image.

It will just look like donate button. But actually it is ordinary button.

And one more big different is that on paypal users will simply see pay/confirm button while making payment. For a real donate button, the button text is set to "Make Donation".

And remember! PayPal will not give u additional benefit granted for donations. They will charge you according to normal transaction fee.

Comment: It's legal? No problem with terms and conditions?